# How to add images inside an item of a list in Gutenberg

Tags: images, block-editor, list

I'm about to move to WordPress (from markdown), and I noticed that the Gutenberg editor won't allow the use of images within list items.

It kind of does with the *"inline image"* feature, but in this case, the image won't be treated as such, and we won't be able to add the "alt" or "caption" attribute or even style the image in any way.
The image won't be considered an "image block".

[image]

So, I'm wondering... how do you guys add images that are within the items of a list?

Something like:

- Item 1
- Item 2
  [Image here]

  Text  here
- Item 3
  [Image here]

The other "workaround" that I found is to basically **break the list** into 2 lists and place the images in between lists. But I'm unsure if this will have any kind of negative effects in terms of SEO.

We are basically saying:

"This is not a list, these are multiple lists of items with images in between".

"The image doesn't belong to this item on the list".

In fact, there's no way to add paragraphs (`<p>`) inside a a list item (`<li>`). Doing enter just adds a line jump instead (`<br>`)

[image]

I can only achieve it if I add the HTML on the code input:

[image]

Comment: what are you trying to build that requires this? There may be alternative ways of doing it that don't require solving this problem of images in lists. Note that you can use shift + enter to insert a line break in a list, putting a paragraph/`p` tag in there might not be valid HTML though

Comment: It's for a blog. But what concerns me is that WordPress is not using the lists in the way that it should. Rather it breaks the lists in two or the images we add are not treated as images and therefore will have a negative impact in our page SEO. 

I thought WordPress was optimised for SEO but I guess I was wrong?

Comment: that didn't really answer my question, I've written lots of blog posts and not needed to solve this problem, can you be more specific about what requires this in your blog post? Your comments on SEO don't make any sense without more context. If you wanted maximum SEO, especially for something with step by step instructions would you not use the dedicated markup tools Google provides for exactly that? Or headings so it's well structured? https://www.google.com/webmasters/markup-helper/u/0/

Comment: Imagine an article with headings h1, h2, h3. 
Then a H3 has a step-by-step guide on how to do something. It uses a bulleted list for it. It looks better having it indented and with bullets. Each step has images, videos, quotes, or multiple paragraphs.

Now, I found no way to do this in WordPress, while doing it in Markdown was very easy. 
I'm not sure what markup tools are you referring to. Mind sharing them?

Comment: I thought I did at the end of my comment, this might be more appropriate: https://developers.google.com/search/docs/appearance/structured-data/how-to. What you're describing though sounds better as headings, e.g. wikihow, and there are blocks that don't exist in markdown, e.g. the rows/stacks/media text block, etc. What you're asking for is fundamentally an inline image but using paragraph tags inside an `<li>` component, currently that's not possible _if you're asking literally_ without manually editing HTML, and would need changes to be made. But that's an X Y problem

Comment: Note that if you wanted to build your own block you could build a list block that allowed tables/groups/image blocks directly, the limitation is not with WordPress or its ability to use HTML lists, but with the implementation of that specific block that's bundled with core. Likewise there are other blocks and ways to achieve a list of things that don't involve `<ul>` tags, lists, etc, and other ways to put a bullet point on something. It may be that what serves you best is actually a stylised h4 and an indented group block

Comment: Yeap, I might have to consider replacing "complex lists" (with images or extra items on each list-item) for H4s. Then use proper lists for "simple lists" that won't contain anything besides text on each list-item. Then style those H4s in a way that separates them better from the rest of the text. Indenting them or so. Thanks for your feedback on the topic!

Comment: The only problem that comes to my mind is... how to style the content of the H4 without having to do it manually on WordPress.

I'm basically copying/pasting from Google Docs, and styling those differently will for sure require some manual action, which is always prompt to human errors and slower.

Comment: you can style them globally with the site editor, or `theme.json` if it's a theme of your own creation/child theme. If you're happy to write some JS and CSS you can create a block style for headings, then it'll show in the sidebar and selecting it will apply a HTML class you can style ( or you can add the class to any heading but that's more manual work ). Also not sure how your lists are setup if they're posts or if they're in a custom post type separated from other articles, but you could use the CSS classes in the body tag to style H4's just on that custom post type

Comment: e.g. on my site i have a talks custom post type, I could style H4's on just the talks with `.single-tomjn_talks h4 { color: hotpink; }`